# How to reduct the terms of differential equation?

Tags: differential-equations, geometry, differential-geometry

How can one bring the terms of a differential equation below to a standard form with coefficients before h[s], h'[s], h''[s] and their powers?

Or, better, can someone help me with solving it with respect to h[s] by means of Wolfram Mathematica?

```
r[s_, t_] := {s, f[s]*Cos[t], h[s]*Sin[t]}
r1[s_, t_] := D[r[s, t], s] // Simplify
r2[s_, t_] := D[r[s, t], t] // Simplify
g11[s, t] := r1[s, t].r1[s, t] // Simplify
g22[s, t] := r2[s, t].r2[s, t] // Simplify
g12[s, t] := r1[s, t].r2[s, t] // Simplify

detG := g11[s, t].g22[s, t] - g12[s, t].g12[s, t] // Simplify
derivG = D[detG, s] // FullSimplify

derivG==0
```

Comment: The dots `.` in the definition of detG seem to be wrong I think

Comment: @UlrichNeumann thank you!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann how would you recommend me to solve the equation with respect to h[s]? I need to find the correspondence between h[s] and f[s]

Comment: `DSolve["your ode",h[s],s]`

Answer (score 1):

The dots . in the definition of detG seem to be wrong I think

Try

```
detG = g11[s, t] g22[s, t] - g12[s, t] g12[s, t] // Simplify
derivG = D[detG, s] // FullSimplify;

derivG == 0

(*2 (Cos[t]^2 h[
  s] ((1 + Derivative[1][f][s]^2) Derivative[1][h][s] + 
   Cos[t]^2 h[s] Derivative[1][f][s] (f^\[Prime]\[Prime])[s]) + 
f[s]^2 Sin[t]^4 Derivative[1][h][s] (h^\[Prime]\[Prime])[s] + 
f[s] Sin[
  t]^2 (Cos[t]^2 h[s] Derivative[1][h][s] (f^\[Prime]\[Prime])[
     s] + Derivative[1][f][
     s] (1 + Derivative[1][h][s]^2 + 
      Cos[t]^2 h[s] (h^\[Prime]\[Prime])[s]))) == 0*)
```